# Filtering literal object using functional programming

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js, object-literal

I wonder if this question has a functional programmiong approach. I have a literal object and some keys:

```
var obj= {'a':20, 'b':44, 'c':70};
var keys = ['a','c'];
```

And I want to obtain:

```
{'a':20', 'c':70}
```

But without for loop. I tried:

```
_.object(keys, ._map(keys, function(key){return obj[key];}))
```

Giving the result but it seems quite complex ..

Comment: is `'a':2'` or `'a':20'`?

Comment: @sherali, true that was a typo! corrected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you use `underscore.js`, try method [`_.pick()`](http://underscorejs.org/#pick), which was implemented specifically for that:

```js
var obj = {
  'a': 20,
  'b': 44,
  'c': 70
};
var keys = ['a', 'c'];

console.log( _.pick(obj, keys) );
// Object {a: 20, c: 70}
```

```html
<script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is great, one day is not enough to study all underscore.js :) Many thanks!!

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel You are welcome! I would also recommend you to have a look at [lodash](https://lodash.com/) library, which I consider more neat and fast.

Comment: This seems promising! Many thanks, will try to read this asap!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `.reduce()`:

```
var extracted = keys.reduce(function(o, k) {
  o[k] = obj[k];
  return o;
}, {});
```

The `.reduce()` method (known as "inject" or "fold" in some other languages) iterates through the values of the array. Each one is passed to the function along with the initial value passed as the second parameter. The function does whatever it needs to do with each array entry and returns the value to be passed on the next iteration.

The pattern above is pretty typical: start with an empty object and add to it with each function call.

Comment: this is even less a one liner than my solution ... I really wouldl ike something concise and clean.

Comment: @Shilly huh? The function iterates through the values in the `keys` array already. There's no need to verify that each key is in the array.